# How to permanently hide dropbox icon in System Tray

Tags: dropbox, system-tray

I want to hide the dropbox icon in my system tray. I can right click the tray, and in the entries menu, set dropbox to "hidden". But when I reboot my computer, dropbox autostarts (`dropbox start -i`), and reappears in the systems tray. Is there any way to hide the icon permanently? I do want the dropbox daemon to run and sync in the background, I just don't want or need the icon.

I've seen lots of questions asking the reverse (the icon has disappeared and people want it back) but I couldn't find anything about this.

I am running Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I see what you see. The changes are written to`~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` in the appropriately named `hiddenItems=` but seems to include a PID or two. I guess that messes up things on a reboot?

Comment: good find! I tried removing the PID, i.e. changing to `hiddenItems=dropbox-client` but that didn't make the icon go away. I restarted `plasmashell` to make sure the config file was re-read.

Comment: A related reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a51zbf/dropbox_system_tray_icon_keeps_reappearing_after/ though the response to a bug link seems less related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like others said, the list of hidden icons can be found in `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`, after `hiddenItems=`, separated with commas, and the problem is Dropbox icon name includes some ID at the end, which changes in every login.

My workaround is to include all 10000 posibilities, since that ID has always 4 digits. I generated them (you can find them [here](https://pastebin.com/v2iFwT6e)), and included them at the end of `hiddenItems=` line (note that the list cannot have any line breaks).

It is not an intuitive solution, but it works perfectly (tested in Manjaro, with KDE Plasma 5.16.2, but should work in Kubuntu as well).

EDIT: bad news. That ID is in fact the PID associated to Dropbox process. By default, maximum PID value is 32768, so there are much more possibilities than I thought. Including them all might be possible, but it would mean 661.2 KiB of data in one single line, and when I try to select it using a text editor, it stops responding, so I couldn't even try to update the solution...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for the problem in the accepted answer, you could force Dropbox to open with a specific PID by running it with `sudo echo 10000 > /proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid; dropbox start -i`, which will cause the next process to have PID 10001 (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122592/how-to-set-process-id-in-linux-for-a-specific-program). Unfortunately, Dropbox actually creates a bunch of processes and takes a while to start up, so you probably still need to add a couple of hundred PIDs to the `hiddenItems` line, but at least you can narrow down the range a bit.

Alternatively, you could disable the Dropbox icon altogether by clearing the `DISPLAY` environment variable when starting it. To do this, go to "System Settings" > "Autostart", select "Dropbox", click the "Properties..." button, and in the "Application" tab change the value of the "Command" field from `dropbox start -i` to `DISPLAY= dropbox start -i` (with a space after the `=` but not before). The downside of this approach is you don't have access to the icon at all any more, and don't get notifications (e.g. if a file is added, or there are connection problems that mean files aren't being synced).

I don't think there's really a clean option here - in the end I decided to just live with the icon, even though it's the only icon in my system tray that isn't monochrome, so it keeps catching my attention.